# How to read a integer value from a string in C++?

Tags: c++, string, input

For example, let say a string is "1 3 -1 3 4 5" and i just simply wanted to extract all those integers.

I am looking for easy way to do this. Most others I have seen need to use stodi.h class, and I am looking to avoid using additional class.

Comment: ah... I already checked through that thread. I will just try else where

Comment: Have you tried `std::istringstream`?  I've heard that you can use the stream extraction operators on it.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Yes! I have been trying it, and I was able to make a little progress on it.

Comment: (also, this was for a programming site called 'CodinGame', and wasn't sure what are default libraries are. But I am getting more familiarity as it goes. Thanks y'll)